# Can I Hide the Site Contents Link with Permissions in SP2013?

Tags: permissions

It appears even as a Visitor, you can still access the Site Contents.

Is there a way to remove this link from the Quick Launch and Actions menu using Permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a solution.  I created a new permission level copied from "read" and called it "Restricted Visitors". I then removed the "View Application Pages" property checkbox.  Still testing this out.

Comment: I'm interested in your test results on this. In particular, does it prevent viewing things like: New, Edit, View, and Upload forms; list views; wiki page editing; viewing version histories; exporting a list; datasheet view (now called Quick Edit); Office Web App views...

Comment: ... that is correct; even I celebrated when I tried the above option but then quickly realised that the users cannot see any type of forms or list lol.  Shame there is option to remove the link from the left-side-navigation at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to be able to see the site and the items in it, you should never prohibit them seeing the pages in a site. This makes them not to be able to see the site at all.
However, people won't see libraries in the application page if they do not have access to them ...
In the version I use (foundation) I don't have the possibility to remove the "view application page" checkbox.